# Is everybody abandoning Expression Engine now?

Tags: development

I've come back to redeveloping an old site that was on EE 2.8.1. When I looked around at the likes of http://eeinsider.com/ or ee-garage.com, and so on, I see blogs that have stopped. Support dating back to 2015. So I went to good ol' Pixel and Tonic. Whoa, they dumped EE onto EE-Harbor.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2):

P+T are unsurprisingly focusing on Craft CMS, which they created a few years back.

Craft has many similarities with EE and it seems that - at least as far as the online slack community goes - many EE mages are now also working on / with Craft these days.

If others have moved on to other CMSs - in part this must be due to problems associated with the botched launch of EE3.  The first releases of EE3 were incomplete and few EE2 addons had EE3 versions available at that time.

This triggered a chicken-egg issue: without an equivalent set of addons migrating EE2 sites to EE3 wasn't really possible, but since the migrations were not taking place, the market for EE3 addons was smaller than before (as presumably EE3 sales were to people doing new builds that - reflecting the lack of addon availability - didn't need many addons) - so after launch addon authors didn't have much incentive to put in the effort / investment into updating either.  Some, like P+T despite initially saying they would get around to rewriting EE2 addons for EE3 concluded it wasn't worth doing at all and either abandoned EE2 addons or sold them on to other firms / developers, others just took a very long time to complete the work.

We're now a long way down the track from the EE3 launch now, and things are much better than they were: there are at least some alternatives for all the major EE2 addons around.

EE3 itself is stable and fast, and has a roadmap for development (at least Ellis Labs are beginning to refer to EE4 at least as a concept).  However it is hard to know what impact the the lost year and general confusion surrounding the launch of EE3 has done to the long term viability of the CMS.

HTH

Comment: Up to this point in my career I've build sites and web apps almost exclusively with EE but my projects have grown in complexity I often find myself trying to shoehorn ways to do things into EE's methods or turning directly to queries or the DB class to make things work in the way that I need it to. As such, I've started working more and more with Laravel and I'm starting to roadmap my major apps to Laravel from EE. 

EE is very stable and fast for most cases and I've enjoyed a lot of success with both EE2 and EE3. I'm just at a point where it's easier to go full custom.

Comment: Very interesting I'm in the exact same position and I also started looking at Laravel lately.